# Texstudio bibliography templates

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

When I use the `Texstudio` tools for generating bibliography commands (in the `biber` setup I guess), I get the following style of keys:

```
OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
OPTlanguage = {language},
OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
OPTvolume = {volume},
OPTpart = {part},
OPTedition = {edition},
OPTvolumes = {volumes},
```

Does anyone know what this `OPT` thing is, and why does `Texstudio` uses it?

Comment: I can only surmise that `OPT` stands for `optional`. (For a given entry type, BibTeX distinguishes between required, optional, and ignored fields.) If you want to provide a value for some of these fields, you should remove the `OPT` part from the field names and write, e.g., `language = "French",`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look that up too: Section 4.3 of the user manual defines those as "optional entries" hence the prefix "OPT".
As Mico mentioned if you want any of the optioal stuff to appear, you will need to remove the "OPT" in front and insert the information.
EDIT: Forgot one bit of information from the manual:
"Note: the optional fields can be automatically deleted with the "Clean" command of the "Bibliography" menu."
But I would assume you are better off to manage your bibliography with an external program like JabRef. It will generate entries based on your entries and leaves out other stuff straight away.

Comment: Um... OK. So the prefix makes them comments for `biber`, I reckon?